# Smoothness of the squared distance function on a Riemannian manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $\left(M, g\right)$ be a complete Riemannian manifold. Let us fix a point $p \in M$ and consider the squared distance function
$$
r(x) := \operatorname{dist}(x, p)^2.
$$
It is well-known that $r$ is a smooth function on $M\setminus Cut(p)$, where $Cut(p)$ is the cut locus of $p$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1834260/42386) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/21295). So it may happen that $r$ is singular on some points in $Cut(p)$.

Now, embed $M$ into the Euclidean space isometricly, then the squared distance function $r$ is the restriction of the Euclidean squared distance function to the submanifold $M$. In particular, $r$ is smooth on $M$. In the book Morse theory by J.Milnor, this distance function is used as a Morse function.

I found it very confusing to have these two seemingly contradict statements. Did I miss something? Are there any good examples?

Comment: Why should $r$ be the restriction of the Euclidean distance after you isometrically imbed? Just because something is isometrically imbedded doesn't mean a geodesic in the sub manifold is a geodesic in the big manifold, right?

Comment: The instrinic and exstrinic distance are the same if and only if $M$ is a flat plane.

Comment: @Timkinsella,@John Ma. Thanks for the comments. Now I can see my mistake.